# Load huge tree with OPENJPA

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, db2, openjpa

I have to load a tree (folders and files) with JPA. But there are more than 1000 nodes, and it take 14 sec to load the whole tree.

Categorie.java :

```
public class Categorie implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idcategorie;
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "IDCATPARENT")
private Categorie categorieParent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categorieParent", cascade = ALL)
private List<Categorie> listeCategorie = new ArrayList<Categorie>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categorieParent", cascade = ALL)
private List<Fichier> listeFichier = new ArrayList<Fichier>();
```

Fichier.java :

```
public class Fichier implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idfichier;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "IDCATEGORIE")
private Categorie categorieParent;
```

The data are store in DB2, and i use to load the tree :

```
SELECT c FROM Categorie c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.listeCategorie
SELECT c FROM Categorie c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.listeFichier
```

How can I load it faster ?

Thank's, and sorry for my english ...

EDIT : 
Query generated by OpenJPA

```
SELECT t0, t1, t2 FROM SCHEMA.Categorie t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.Categorie t1 ON t0.IDCATPARENT = t1.idcategorie LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.Categorie t2 ON t0.idcategorie = t2.IDCATPARENT WHERE (t0.supprimer = CAST(? AS BIGINT)) ORDER BY t2.IDCATPARENT ASC 
openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1860790064, conn 339897564> [56 ms] spent

SELECT t0, t1, t2 FROM SCHEMA.Categorie t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.Categorie t1 ON t0.IDCATPARENT = t1.idcategorie LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA.Fichier t2 ON t0.idcategorie = t2.IDCATEGORIE WHERE (t0.supprimer = CAST(? AS BIGINT)) ORDER BY t2.IDCATEGORIE ASC  
openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1860790064, conn -1256330574> [210 ms] spent
```

So it is pretty fast to call the database, but after, it take 10-15 sec to get result as a list...

Comment: Have you tried lazy loading the set? For example, modify the join annotation to be `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categorieParent", cascade = ALL)`. Also, why do you need to load all the nodes?

Comment: By default, the fetchtype of OnetoMany is Lazy, i already tried to switch this mode, but the result is approximately the same.

I have to provide an admin interface to manage the tree, and I have to export all the nodes to jSon. So i must load all tree :(

Comment: I'd start by enabling OpenJPA SQL logging (openjpa.Log=SQL=trace) to see if anything jumps out at you.

Comment: I edited my answer, with logging trace of OpenJPA